# How to store encryption key in php?

Tags: php, encryption

So i have a project that is encrypting user information upon registering. currently i am saving the encryption key of the user in the database, my professor told me to have a key management.
the problem is i dont know where to store the encryption key and how to decrypt the data if i have found a way to store the key.

this is my php code for encryption:

```
//key for encryption and decryption we can also generate a random key
          $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

        //function for encryptiong the data
          function aes_encrypt($data, $key) {
               $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
               $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
               $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
               return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
          }
        //DECRYPT FUNCTION
          function aes_decrypt($data, $key) {
               $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
               list($encrypted_data, $iv) = array_pad(explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2),2,null);
               return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
          }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, "i dont know where to store the encryption key", why not store the key in a constant : const MY_KEY = "...."; + [your code who use the key]

Comment: If you're using a different key for each user, you have to store the key in the database - but in encrypted form. Use a master key to encrypt all the user keys. The master key is a constant which you should define in a separate config file, which doesn't get uploaded to your git repo.

Comment: Or you use hybrid encryption, where the AES key is generated dynamically and RSA encrypted (and then delivered together with the payload data)

Comment: im thinking of storing the encryption keys in a text file/config file but idont know how to implement/do it.

Comment: That topic is too broad to cover in a Stack Overflow question, unfortunately. I would recommend searching online for how to store encryption data/keys securely, and attempt an implementation based on what you find. Then, if you encounter a problem or have a question about a specific step, you can ask here about *that*.